# Visibility issue force.com

Tags: force.com, visibility

I have a problem of visibility on Account. Note that the page of the account is a VFP page.
Profile do not have view all 
Account is private.
We develop a specifique homepage depending on the user profile which call a specific VFP page.

But when log as a User, I can see all the account .
Can you help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is that extentions/controller is with sharing or without sharing?. The by default is without sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a class is not declared either [**with sharing or without sharing**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm), then by default, such a class is executed in system mode, i.e. without sharing mode which means anybody can see anybody data and if you are updating data it can be updated by anybody.

Comment: Thank you i found the solution, they were a sharing with this account in the code